# Surface area of revolution $x=\ln(y)$ about $x$ axis

Tags: definite-integrals, area

My question is regarding finding the surface area of revolution of an equation. The equation is $x=\ln(y)$, with bounds of $0 \le x \le 1$ about the $x$-axis. I know the integral for solving this would be:

$$    2\pi \int_1^e y\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y^2}}\,dy $$
But I've tried integrating by parts and u-substitution but I can't seem to get the answer of:

$$    \pi\left[e\sqrt{1+e^2} + \ln\left(e + \sqrt{1+e^2}\right) - \sqrt{2} - \ln\left(\sqrt{2} +1\right)\right] $$

If anyone can help me with this integration I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have the same number of left and right parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it

Comment: No worries. Use the math formatting next time.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out but I will for next time thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the argument of the square root function.
Then use trigonometric substitution followed by integration by parts.

In more detail:

$$\int_1^e y\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{y^2}}\,dy = \int_1^e \sqrt{y^2 + 1}\,dy.$$

Using trigonometric substitution with $y = \tan \phi$, we obtain
$$\int_1^e \sqrt{y^2 + 1}\,dy = \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec^3 \phi \,d\phi.$$
Integrating by parts with $u = \sec\phi$, $dv = \sec^2\phi\,d\phi$ yields
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec^3 \phi \,d\phi = e\sqrt{1 + e^2} - \sqrt{2} - \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec\phi \tan^2\phi\,d\phi.$$
Since
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec\phi \tan^2\phi = \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec^3 \phi\,d\phi - \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec\phi \,d\phi,$$
it follows that 
\begin{align}
2 \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec^3 \phi\,d\phi &= e\sqrt{1 + e^2} - \sqrt{2} + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(e)} \sec\phi\,d\phi \\
&= e\sqrt{1 + e^2} - \sqrt{2} + \ln\left(e + \sqrt{1 + e^2}\right) - \ln\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right).
\end{align}

Hence the result on multiplying by $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much, the only thing I don't follow is how you got the sec^3? I understand why you changed the bounds, but how did you get sec^3? When I tried to work out the problem I got sec^2, I'm not sure where I went wrong

Comment: You're welcome. The integrand is $\sec\phi$ and $dy = \sec^2 \phi\,d\phi$.

Comment: It helps me if you hit +1.

Comment: I would but I don't have a rep of 15 yet so unfortunately I can only choose it as the correct answer

Comment: No worries John

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Would not straightforward $ y = e^x $ be easier?

$$ SA=  2 \pi \int_1^e y/\cos\phi \,dx   ;\  \,\,\tan \phi = e^x $$

Comment: It would, but I need to solve it this way

Comment: OK, for a check in the working both give the same expressions, same result.

Comment: I know, but my professor said this might be on the test and I can't figure it out so I thought I'd ask on here